# Find first instance of space in string

Tags: sql-server, position, substring

I am trying to return the first 'word' in a string by finding the first instance of a space ' ' in the string field Part_Comment. Examples of strings in the field Part_Comment are:

```
13088V21 () (FAB)
G16707 (FOLD) ()
16636U01.01
```

I have tried:

```
substring(Part_Comment from 1 for position(' ' in Part_Comment)-2) as "AssyNo",
```

which comes up with an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'." But it works fine when I just use Part_Comment by itself.

```
substring(Part_Comment from 1) as "AssyNo",
```

Same error as above

```
left(Part_Comment,10) as "AssyNo",
```

This works, but I need to use the `position` function or something else to find the ' ' substring. But apparently the `position` function returns 0 when more than one instance occurs.

I imagine this is a pretty common thing that users want, so there must be an easy solution.

Comment: Are you sure you're using FB2.5? Because support for length (and startpos) being any valid integer expression was added in 2.0, versions below it require that the length must be integer literal.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Firebird? _"Incorrect syntax near the keyword .."_ is not a Firebird error message, but a Microsoft SQL Server error message.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel MS SQL or MySQL? I believe I saw that error often on SQLFiddle with MYSQL 5.6

Comment: @Arioch'The MySQL uses _"Incorrect syntax near .."_ (so without _'the keyword'_)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - you are right! It was MS SQL. So I am using the wrong function as position doesn't exist.

Comment: Your problem then is sooner on of `substring`. Substring on SQL Server uses `SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )`, not `SUBSTRING ( expression from start [to length] )`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with LEFT and POSITION like so:

```
LEFT(Part_Comment, POSITION(' ' in Part_Comment)-1))
```

**EDIT**

as @Arioch 'The in comment suggested, safety need to be implemented

```
  CASE POSITION(' ' in Part_Comment)
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Part_Comment'
    ELSE LEFT(Part_Comment, POSITION(' ' in Part_Comment)-1)
  END
```

Comment: i bet you have to add a `coalesce` for a case there was no space at all

Comment: @Arioch'The I've made EDIT. Is this OK, or could be done another way.

Comment: well, `COALESCE` function is much more concise and easier to read = safer to write than `IIF` or full blown `CASE`. For example you just DID make an error by putting Part_Comment into quotes :-D / And also Part_Comment itself might be `NULL`

Comment: `LEFT(Part_Comment, COALESCE(POSITION(' ' in Part_Comment)-1), 0))`